# Defining indexes+elements in an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, associative

Why does the following code:

```
if (isset($_GET['trainType']) && isset($_GET['onTime']) && isset($_GET['gotSeat'])) {
    $train[0]['trainType'] = $_GET['trainType'];
    $train[0]['trainType']['onTime'] = $_GET['onTime'];
    $train[0]['trainType']['gotSeat'] = $_GET['gotSeat'];   
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($train);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Return the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [trainType] => tLine
        )

)
```

I had initially assumed it would return something more resembling to this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [trainType] => 'passenger'
            Array =>
                (
                    [onTime] => true
                    [gotSeat] => true
                )

        )

)
```

Any guidance on what I should do to achieve what I am trying to do? I am hoping that my code makes what I am trying to do obvious.

Comment: can you var_dump() your $_GET array?

Comment: `trainType = string 'VLine' (length=5)
onTime = string 'true' (length=4)
gotSeat = string 'true' (length=4)`

Comment: so you are trying to append to a string as though it were an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will set `trainType` to a string value:

```
$train[0]['trainType'] = 'hello';
```

Then these lines will actually be used for character substitution, with a slight twist:

```
$train[0]['trainType']['onTime'] = 'foo';
$train[0]['trainType']['gotSeat'] = 'bar';
```

Both `onTime` and `gotSeat` will result in `0` (because you're working with a string) and will replace the first character with `f` then `b`.

Therefore `print_r($train)` returns:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [trainType] => bello
        )

)
```

Here is how I would format this data:

```
// define our list of trains
$train = array();

// create a new train
$new = new stdClass;
$new->type = 'a';
$new->onTime = 'b';
$new->gotSeat = 'c';

// add the new train to our list
$train[] = $new;
```

The result of `print_r($trains)`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => a
            [onTime] => b
            [gotSeat] => c
        )

)
```

Accessing this data:

```
echo $trains[0]->type; // returns 'a'
echo $trains[0]->onTime; // returns 'b'
echo $trains[0]->gotSeat; // returns 'c'
```

Comment: That is pretty cool. I've never really worked with objects before, but this is probably what I should have been doing. Even though I could have originally done this w/ my original array, this answer has given me an idea which will improve my code in the long run so I appreciate that. One question I had however is why the contents of the array was mixed instead of ignored, like you said? (ie: VLine became TLine (replaced the first letter of VLine with the T from True (from the other $_GET vars)

Comment: I've updated my answer to solve this problem. It wasn't immediately clear until I ran a test locally.

Answer (score 0):

You are implicitly setting (or needing) a key = 0 for

```
array (
  "onTime" => true,
  "gotSeat" => true
)
```

So you must instead just do this:

```
if (isset($_GET['trainType']) && isset($_GET['onTime']) && isset($_GET['gotSeat'])) {
    $train[0]['trainType'] = $_GET['trainType'];
    $train[0][0]['onTime'] = $_GET['onTime'];
    $train[0][0]['gotSeat'] = $_GET['gotSeat'];
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($train);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Note that all I did was to change the incorrect `$train[0]['trainType']['onTime']` to `$train[0][0]['trainType']` in your code, and similarly for `gotSeat`.

Or you can define a new key, maybe like this: `$train[0]['booking']['onTime'] = ...`